# Data structure to represent a solution of 2D material cutting?

Tags: c++, data-structures, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am working on the cutting problem, and I need to figure out how
to represent the solution.

For example look at this image, where the gray areas are unused material.

[image]

Can you please recommend me possible representations? By the way I am using c++ for this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show source code for some of the representations you've already tried?

Comment: This is very much a kD tree for 2D -- implement a binary tree where each node stores a dimension (X or Y), a value along that dimension (between 0 and 1, where 0 is one end and 1 is the other) and two pointers which point to the children of that node. Also implement two kinds of leaf: GrayLeaf and WhiteLeaf. Makes sense?

Comment: Nope sorry, I don't have any source code yet or representations thought of. But yes it seems I will need a tree structure maybe. I am not sure, I haven't studied this problem before.

Comment: +1 on the tree structure!

Comment: Actually no need for tree because what the tree encodes is order of cutting, and I don't care about the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a vector of structs `std::vector<sub> areas;` like

```
struct sub
{
  size_t x, y;
  size_t extent_x, extent_y;
  sub (void) : x(0U), y(0U), extent_x(0U), extent_y(0U) { }
};
```

Where (x,y) as well as (x+extent_x, y+extent_y) are mapped on the Points of the total image.
This vector may either store used or unused parts of the Image.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D image looks like a system memory. Gray area is un-allocated memory and white space is allocated memory. The solution can be similar to memory management done by OS.